# How to deploy iPhone app and WatchOS app(App extension) on TestFlight using Azure devops pipeline

Tags: ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, watchos, azure-devops-extensions

I have tried below mentioned YML file in Azure pipeline but getting error during the run. Without the extension it was working fine

> ❌  error: Provisioning profile "watchkit-beta-extension-appstore" has
> app ID "dev.app.watchkitapp.watchkitextension", which does not match
> the bundle ID "dev.app.watchkitapp". (in target 'Watch' from project
> 'PORJECT_NAME')

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  - group: iOS-build-variables

steps:

# CocoaPods
# Install CocoaPods dependencies for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects
- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs:
    forceRepoUpdate: false

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'Distribution_Certificates.p12'
    certPwd: '$(key.appCertificatePassword)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install MainTarget provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'beta_appstore_profile.mobileprovision'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install Watch app provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'watchkit-beta-appstore.mobileprovision'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install Watch extension app provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'watchkit-beta-extension-appstore.mobileprovision'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: '$(key.devrelease.scheme)'
    sdk: 
    configuration: '$(key.devrelease.configuration)'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'PORJECT_NAME.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath
    signingOption: 'manual'
    packageApp: true
    signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
    provisioningProfileUuid: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
   
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.ipa'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    overWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: AppStoreRelease@1
  displayName: 'Publish to the App Store TestFlight track'
  inputs:
    serviceEndpoint: 'AppleStoreServiceConnection'
    appIdentifier: '$(key.devrelease.appPackageName)'
    ipaPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.ipa'
    shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: true
    installFastlane: false
    releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
```